# Toggling button state on matplotlib NavigationToolbar programmatically

Tags: python, matplotlib, wxpython, wxwidgets

I am embedding a figure with a customized `NavigationToolbar2WxAgg` so that I can (hopefully) easily control the state of the toolbar.  I would like to be able to toggle the zoom and pan buttons, but I'm having some difficulty getting it to work properly.  My code for the toolbar is

```py
class CustomNavToolbar(NavigationToolbar2WxAgg):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        NavigationToolbar2WxAgg.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        self.DeleteToolByPos(7)  # Deletes the adjust subplots button

    @property
    def IsActive(self):
        return self._active is not None

    def DeactivateAll(self):
        if self._active == 'PAN':
            self.pan('off')
        elif self._active == 'ZOOM':
            self.zoom()
```

with the idea that I can just call `DeactivateAll()` method to turn off any mode that is currently active.  Unfortunately, this doesn't work quite right.  The mode is disabled, but the button itself stays toggled.  And when I click the button again, the mode is enabled, but the button is untoggled.

My google-fu couldn't come up with a working solution, can someone point me towards the right method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this by programmatically pushing the button.

If you look at the code for `zoom` there is the line

```
self.ToggleTool(self.wx_ids['Pan'], False)
```

which I assume toggles the button off, so just include a similar line:

```
def DeactivateAll(self):
    if self._active == 'PAN':
        self.pan('off')
        self.ToggleTool(self.wx_ids['Pan'], False)
    elif self._active == 'ZOOM':
        self.ToggleTool(self.wx_ids['Zoom'], False)
        self.zoom()
```

I suspect you can make this even simpler:

```
 def DeactivateAll(self):
    self.ToggleTool(self.wx_ids['Pan'], False)
    self.ToggleTool(self.wx_ids['Zoom'], False)
```

and let the call-backs do their jobs.